# При позиционирование градиента на картинку, исчезает градиент, хотя в stack работает

Tags: html, css

```css
 .baner-img{
display: flex;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;

}

.gradient {
    position: relative;

}

.gradient-color {
    width: 100%;
    height: 551px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, #0E0E0E 66.15%);
    position: absolute; 
    /* При position: absolute градиент исчезает */
}
```

```html
<section class="baner">
    <img class="baner-img" src="https://cdn-edge.kwork.ru/pics/t3/23/27100204-64636693aaf80.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="gradient">
        <div class="gradient-color"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в сниппете градиент никуда не исчез. Ты можешь отредактировать сниппет так, чтобы проблема воспроизводилась?

Comment: Можешь подсказать что такое сниппет)

Comment: Аноним, я отредактировала ваш вопрос по просьбе Grundy. Сейчас кто-нибудь примет правку

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: [Что такое сниппеты?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999)

Comment: @darinkapoznyak , а ты уверен, что в том месте `absolute` поставил?

Comment: @Grundy, когда у Анонима там был relative, то градиент как раз был...

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно градиент закинуть поверх картинки.  Не знаю  правильно ли я позиционировал gradient к gradient-color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.baner {
  width: 660px;
  height: 440px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.baner-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 2%;
}

.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, #0E0E0E 66.15%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<section class="baner">
  <img class="baner-img" src="https://cdn-edge.kwork.ru/pics/t3/23/27100204-64636693aaf80.jpg" alt="#">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</section>
```

Аноним, я правильно поняла ваше тз?

Comment: Да, спасибо!!!!

Comment: P.S. там, где у вас % градиента.. там где у вас 66.15% я бы что-нибудь поменяла.. например, заменила бы на 83.15%... но, дело ваше)

Comment: Фоновый цвет макета полностью черный #181818.  Я специально убрал фон чтобы можно было увидеть где находится градиент.